# %CPU reaching to 70% for 100 concurrent requests

Tags: node.js

When we try to run `ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://    127.0.0.1:3000/` %cpu almost reaching to 70%. Is this default nature of node or do we need to modify any settings of anything to decrease cpu usage?

Response of the request is just a "Hello world" and our machine is having **2GB RAM** and node is running with current version.

I heard that nodejs can handle more than **100K concurrent requests** but I don't understand how they achieve that.

Comment: You should not run `ab` on the same machine. Otherwise the client will also use a lot of CPU.

Comment: may be but node process only reaching to 70%.

Comment: As long as there's CPU-resources available, it seems to make sense for Node to use them as much as possible to handle requests as quickly as possible. What number of reqs/sec are you getting?

Comment: Seems a bit low, but that depends on the hardware of course (my MBP can handle about 6-10K reqs/sec for a simple 'hello world'). But don't forget that you're flooding Node with as many requests as possible to be handled in the shortest possible time, so it will utilize all available CPU time it can get.

Comment: Did you modify any nodejs or v8 settings?